# I'm trying to scrape some web page, but failed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape (Zone-H) to get some information, I found the website will execute JavaScript (called SlowAES).

But the website seems to detect that it is using Selenium ChromeDriver, because I can't download z.js, so I can't connect to the website.

[image: Chrome browser traffic monitor display indicating z.js with status 404]

I've added these two experimental options:

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches',["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension',False)
```

But I still cannot get it to scrape.

Comment: it shows `404` for `z.js` so it can means this file doesn't exists - it doesn't have to be problem with selenium

Comment: better put full URL for this page - or better minimal working code - so we could simply check this directly in browser.